# Can't Figure out why setValue() returns an error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Code I've run v1:

```
  var G = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();  
  var Resp1 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url1, parameters);
  var parResp1 = JSON.parse(Resp1);               
  var k = parseInt(parResp1.time);
  G.getRange("B5").setValues(k);
```

Code v2 Change replaces 4th line with:

```
var k = JSON.stringify(parResp1.time);
```

After I run my Code I get this error message

```
Cannot find method setValues(number). (line 27, file "Code")
```

The Value that is returned is a number but I don't understand why it doesn't see it as one.

What could be going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to update a single cell, in your case getRange("B5") you should use setValue, not setValues

setValues would be used in the case where you want to set the values for a range between two points such as "A1:B2"

Answer (score 2):

While the other answer is correct, it doesn't explain the reason why you are having this error.

As mentioned in the [documentation about](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object)) `setValues()`, the argument for `setValues()` must be a 2 dimensions array (an array of arrays) either built from scratch or captured using `getValues()`.

see The doc below :
[image]

By the way, the funny thing is that the title of your post uses `setValue()` without `S` while your code has the problematic `S` ...