# Google Sheet Script - Date Difference - Current Date() - Date() in spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-apps

I`m trying to calculate dates in my data - NOW() (Current Date) in days

So

```
Dates           Today              Days difference

2019-01-01     2019-03-11            X
2019-02-01     2019-03-11            X
```

and I would like that Today to be updated everyday

Is there way to do this in Script so that "Days difference" can be updated daily automatically?

Also is it possible to highlight any rows with red that are greater than 100 days?

Comment: You can use `=TODAY()`  and `DATEDIF()`  
https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092984?hl=en  &
https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6055612?hl=en&ref_topic=3105385
  ...(or instead of DATEDIF(), maybe just `MINUS(date1, date2)`, since date is measured in days)

Comment: Yea, using formulas are much simpler, but I need these to run on the back-end only - users shouldn`t see any formulas in the cell.. So I need to do these in script

Answer (score 1):

Googlescripts seem to use dates that are basically the same as javascript dates, so you should be able to do something like this:

```js
    var dateFromFirstColumn = new Date("2019-01-01"); 
    var now = new Date();
    var today = new Date(
        now.getFullYear(),
        now.getMonth(),
        now.getDate(),
        0,0,0); // Midnight last night, since presumably the first date is similar
    var todayString = today.toLocaleString(); // Can be written to second column
    var diff = today.getTime() - dateFromFirstColumn.getTime();
    var millisecondsInADay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
    var diffInDays = Math.floor(diff/millisecondsInADay);

    console.log(diffInDays);
```

I can't say for sure that googlescripts supports Math.floor() and the like, but this should get you close.

Assuming the automatic formatting of `.toLocaleString` isn't what you want, you can use the `.getFullYear`, `.getMonth`, and `.getDate` methods (and pad any single-digit days with a leading zero), then concatenate the results into the `YYYY-MM-DD` format. (Note that January is month number zero when converting month numbers to text.)

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date and
https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/features/dates for more info.

Comment: So here is the thing, I actually have tried similar codes before, but apparently, these dates array do not work with .setValues(). So I cannot append these to the existing data`s column...

Comment: W/ this error message, Cannot find method setValues(number)

Comment: Is it because google's `setValues` requires a two-dimensional array? If so, you can build one by wrapping each value in its own sub-array (each with a length of 1), or by using `setValue` instead (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25372356/cant-figure-out-why-setvalue-returns-an-error). Or if you get desperate, just set each cell's value one at a time until you're sure what works, although this would clearly be much slower.  And for highlighting, you could leverage google sheets' conditional formatting (https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)